# Swift - How do I segue from ViewController to TabBarController

Tags: xcode, swift, uistoryboardsegue

How do I add a `ViewController` before a `TabBarController` in Swift? I am using Parse to make a custom login in the `ViewController` which would lead to the `TabBarController`... Help would be appreciated!

Comment: seems like you should just drag a viewController onto storyboard, make it the initial viewController and then segue into your tab bar controller

Comment: I did everything, but how do I segue it into my tab bar controller? Control and dragging doesn't work in this instance

Comment: it depends on the nature you want the segue to happen... try editing your question more to explain what you want to occur.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** Control-drag from yellow symbol (ViewController) to the `TabBarController`

[image]

---

This will create a segue in your `ViewController` menu

[image]

---

**2.** Click this new segue "Show segue to Tab..." and in identity inspector set an identifier name.

[image]

---

**3.** Now when you want to make the segue happen, use call...

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("WhatEveryYouNamedSegue", self)
```

Comment: This is not working in Swift 4 and Xcode 9. 'Receiver (<BestIdAttendance.LoginViewController: 0x7fa7f1c02250>) has no segue with identifier 'LoginToTabBar''. However I set 'LoginToTabBar' name in both code and storyboard. @Chameleon

Comment: @MohdSadham when doing step #2, did you put "LoginToTabBar" in the `identifier` field?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I transfer from the login view controller to my home view controller tab bar.

```
let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVCTabBar") as? UITabBarController

            self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The most common mistake people make is that they use Instead of UITabBarController the name of the VC they go to.

Make sure you use UITabBarController to entry the first view from your TabBarController.